# can't change url , change url in php

Tags: php, url, curl, exchange-server

I have a site developed by developer.. I don't know php or html,

I want to change url of my site. The current url is like:

> abcd.in/index.php?page=9

I want to change it to:

> abcd.in/free_classified_sites1

I tried using .htaccess code

```
'IfModule mod_rewrite.c`
/Enable Rewrite Engine
/RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
/Redirect index.php? Requests
/RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
/RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/system/.*
/RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]
/Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
/RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
/RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
/RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
/RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

**but still new url is like**

*abcd.in/?page=1*

what to do now....

second problem if use .htaccess code , I can't access my sub domain, where I have classified site, but after implementing this code I can't see admin page of my subdomain.

which is like

*classifieds.abcd.in/*

Comment: // this is my index page code
$offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;

  // how many pages we have when using paging?
 maxPage = ceil($numrows/$rowsPerPage);


$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$nav  = '';

for($page = 1; $page <= $maxPage; $page++)

{
   if ($page == $pageNum)
   {
      $nav .= "<li class='active'><a href='javascript:void(0);'>$page</a></li>";
   }
   else
   {
      $nav .= "<li><a href=\"$self?free_classified_sites=$page\">$page</a></li>";
   } 
}

Comment: if ($pageNum > 1)
{
    $page  = $pageNum - 1;
    $prev  = " <a class='fNavPre' href=\"$self?free_classified_sites=$page\">Prev</a>             ";

    $first = " <a class='fNavFst' href=\"$self?free_classified_sites=1\">First Page</a> ";
  } 
  else
  {
       $prev  = '&nbsp;';
      $first = '&nbsp;'; 
   }

   if ($pageNum < $maxPage)
   {
       $page = $pageNum + 1;
     $next = " <a class='fNavNxt' href=\"$self?free_classified_sites=$page\">Next</a> ";

     $last = " <a class='fNavLst' href=\"$self?                free_classified_sites=$maxPage\">Last Page</a> ";
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^free_classified_sites1$ index.php?page=9 [L]
```

Comment: thanx a lot Sumit its working, just 1 problem the ' ? ' is sitll there in url  .in/?free_classified_sites=1

Comment: can i use my site name here in this forum/site?? is it allowed to ?? cause i have many question some of them u will understand after going through my site

Comment: you can directly access `domain.com/index.php?page=9` through `domain.com/free_classified_sites1`

Comment: old url was .in/index.php?page=9                                       now it is changed to  .in/?free_classified_sites=1